# How to make focus(), tabindex and text highlighting work for web components with shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm making reusable Web Components containing shadow DOM and am currently having trouble with focus.

I have a component containing a native input and some text.

I'm trying to have the following working:

- Calling `.focus()` on the component will focus its inner native input
- Using the attribute `tabindex` works
- Pressing "tab" does not focus the component, but rather its inner native input
- Highlighting the text is allowed (using the mouse mousedown + drag)

Here are some things I tried:
https://codepen.io/Spirielle/pen/RwBwJNY

Initially I was using `delegatesFocus` on the component shadow DOM. It works well for focus and tab, but makes the text inside the component unselectable.

Then I tried to remove `delegatesFocus` and instead call the inner input `focus` method whenever `focus` was called on the component, but now I have to press tab twice when the attribute `tabindex` is set on the component.

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me a good-enough solution, so I thought I'd share :)

We bind on `onfocus` instead of `focus`

```
  this.onfocus = opts => {
    inner.focus(opts);
  };
```

It's not perfect since we need to click twice in the text to highlight it, but otherwise all 4 mentioned use cases work.

I updated the codepen with this solution.
https://codepen.io/Spirielle/pen/RwBwJNY

Feel free to suggest something else or comment if something terrible could happen with this approach.